# Server Name not valid in Connect to Server: Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, ssms

I'm trying to step through the Data-Driven Report Subscription setup, but I can't get past [Step 2 of Part 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170596%28SQL.90%29.aspx).

I get no options for Server name other than "browse", which only turns up two instances on the local network.  I tried the alias I use when connecting to the Database Engine (via the SQL Server Configuration Manager), but won't work.  The office IP range is 192.168.x, and all the SQL Server instances are outside the local network (206.x).

Do I need to be using remote desktop to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'drop down' is an UDP broadcast on the SQL Browser port (1433?). It will be broadcast from your workstation, so the 206.* segment will not see it. Putting in the right name should work though.

Comment: Found out the Reporting instances are on a different server entirely.